# jQuery ID and class selector on click function

Tags: jquery

I have this code with click function with a selector of id checkbox input and a class radio button input if either if the two inputs is checked a button will add a attribute of disabled else it will removed the attrib, unfortunately it is not working how can you make it work with different selector when you click either of them it will add a attribute?

Here's the code:

```js
$("#callbackReq input.callbackopt").on("click", function() {
  if ($("#callbackReq input.callbackopt").is(":checked")) {
    $("#submitBtn").attr('disabled','disabled');
  } else {
    $("#submitBtn").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="" id="callbackReq" name="callbackReq">
  Call back 
</label>

<br />
<label class="radio-inline radio-choices">        
  <input class="callbackopt" type="radio" name="acceptedModr" id="approved" value="Y" checked />
  Approved
</label>

<label class="radio-inline radio-choices"> 
  <input class="callbackopt" type="radio" name="acceptedModr" id="rejected" value="N"/>
  Rejected
</label>

<br />

<button class="btn btn-primary move-right" type="submit" value="ENTER" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" disabled>
  Save and Next
</button>
```

Comment: Post the HTML as well, so we can see the elements.

Comment: In other words familiarize yourself with what a [mcve] is all about. We have no way to help when we can't reproduce the issue

Comment: Sorry, done posting the html.

Comment: You want `$("#callbackReq, input.callbackopt")` note the comma

Comment: The checkbox is working but how about the radio button?

Comment: @Jemai I have posted a working solution. Please take a look at it.

Comment: thanks its working now

Comment: @Jemai if you answer was helpful you can always mark it as the correct one or at least vote it up :). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Inside the If statemnt should refer to current element that was clicked. Try change the code inside the if statement like this :

```js
$("#callbackReq,input.callbackopt").on("click", function() {
  if (($(this).is(':checkbox') && $(this).is(":checked")) || $(this).val() == 'Y') {
    $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});

// or this if want radio button only
/*$("#callbackReq,input.callbackopt").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Y') {
    $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="" id="callbackReq" name="callbackReq">Call back
</label>

<br />
<label class="radio-inline radio-choices">
  <input class="callbackopt" type="radio" name="acceptedModr" id="approved" value="Y" />Approved
</label>

<label class="radio-inline radio-choices">
  <input class="callbackopt" type="radio" name="acceptedModr" id="rejected" value="N" checked/>Rejected
</label>

<br />

<button class="btn btn-primary move-right" type="submit" value="ENTER" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" disabled>Save and Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution :). Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#callbackReq, input.callbackopt").on("click", function(){
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
   $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled','disabled');
  } 
  else if ($("input[name='acceptedModr']").is(":checked")) {
   $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled','disabled');
  }
  else if(!$(this).is(":checked"))  {
   $("#submitBtn").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
 <input type="checkbox" value="" id="callbackReq" name="callbackReq" >Call back 
</label>

<br />
<label class="radio-inline radio-choices">        
 <input class="callbackopt" type="radio" name="acceptedModr" id="approved" value="Y"/>Approved
</label>

<label class="radio-inline radio-choices"> 
 <input class="callbackopt" type="radio" name="acceptedModr" id="rejected" value="N"/>Rejected
</label>

<br />

<button class="btn btn-primary move-right" type="submit" value="ENTER" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn">Save and Next</button>
```